# Installing mit-scheme alongside postgres

Tags: postgresql, scheme

I recently started reading [structure and interpretation of a programing language](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html) and as such I want to install the mit-scheme interpreter but I realized whenever I installed it, it uninstalled postgres and whenever I installed postgres it uninstalled mit-scheme. My question is how can I install these two packages alongside each other seeing as I use both.

Comment: Which OS? Which version? Any other information?

Comment: @larry If my answer solves your problem please accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that problem is occurring on **Ubuntu**, most likely it is because you have `32` bit version of `mit-scheme`.

The problem is with packages **libpq5:i386** and **libpq5**.

`postgres` depends on the latter and `mit-scheme` depends on the former package. So as soon as you install `postgres`, **libpq5:i386** is removed to install **libpq5**. (Both `x86` and `x64` versions of `libpq5` don't go together well, apparently.) And that removes `mit-scheme` because `mit-scheme` can no longer run.

So the solution is [**Note** - This solution is for Ubuntu *only*]-

- Install `postgres` this uninstalls x86 `mit-scheme` and its dependencies.
- Download x64 `mit-scheme` from here [x64 mit-scheme](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/196250008/mit-scheme_9.1.1-5_amd64.deb).
- Then run following commands.

> sudo apt-get autoremove
>
> sudo apt-get install libmcrypt4 libpq5
>
> sudo dpkg -i /path/to/mit-scheme_9.1.1-5_amd64.deb